# Migrating content (plugins, posts, pages etc) from local installation to production version

Tags: wordpress

I've just been tasked with updating an existing wordpress site.

I have a local copy of the site running on my machine for development.

The updates will include installing new plugins, customising them, changing content, adding pages, etc.

Once I have made the necessary changes, what is the best way to migrate these changes to the production server? I know about the 'Duplicator' plugin, but that seems to be for migrating entire, new, websites. I am interested in just migrating updates.

Comment: I had to do it once, and I chose to set an 'under maintainance' page because you cannot make all your changes together. Then I took my time to make all my updates properly. May not help you but it' a bit risky to try to upload all your new stuff while users are still able to browse the site.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate, clone, backup, move and transfer an entire site from one location to another.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/